# nvd3.js line chart -- add vertical lines

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to add *several* vertical lines (say 10 or 20) to an nvd3 line chart.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582005/nvd3-line-chart-with-vertical-line) suggests adding a series for this, but I would need to add 20 series, overcrowding the legend and the interactive tooltip.

From what I understand this can't be done out-of-the-box (*please* correct me if I'm wrong), so my question is what is the easiest way of doing this:

1. Add D3 lines to the DOM (how would I go about scale, positioning them horizontally, etc?)
2. Add generic support for this in nvd3
3. Add support for hiding specific series from the legend and from the tooltip, and add 20 series
4. Any other idea?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856060/how-do-i-add-an-average-line-to-an-nvd3-js-stacked-area-chart) may help.

Comment: @Lars: I assume you're advocating for option #1?

Comment: Well that would certainly be less work than the other options. Depends on whether you think you'll need this frequently though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that it wasn't *that* hard. I chose option #3, and the following code changes to `nv.d3.js` got the job done:

In the `legend` model, change

```
function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(data) {
```

... to

```
function chart(selection) {
    selection.each(function(dataUnfiltered) {
        var data = dataUnfiltered.filter(function (d) {
            return !d.disableLegend;
        });
```

and in the `lineChart` model, change:

```
interactiveLayer.dispatch.on('elementMousemove', function(e) {
    lines.clearHighlights();
    var singlePoint, pointIndex, pointXLocation, allData = [];
    data
    .filter(function(series, i) {
      series.seriesIndex = i;
      return !series.disabled;
    })
```

... to

```
interactiveLayer.dispatch.on('elementMousemove', function(e) {
    lines.clearHighlights();
    var singlePoint, pointIndex, pointXLocation, allData = [];
    data
    .filter(function(series, i) {
      series.seriesIndex = i;
      return !series.disabled && !series.disableTooltip;
    })
```

(Obviously this second change would have to be done to each chart model you want to support, say also `cumulativeLineChart` and `stackedAreaChart).

This will enable you to specify, in addition to `color`, `key`, `values`, etc. also `disableTooltip: true` and/or `disableLegend: true`.

Hope this helps someone.